# Position with Compile is acting slower than without

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, compile

For a big matrix 5000 x 5000 or `list2` i am trying to get positions of all
entries `Except[1.0]`. I am using `Position`, however I find it quite odd that with `Compile` the result is comparatively slower.

Any ideas where i might be wrong in my implementation? and I would be grateful if you can let me know of an even faster implementation.

```
pos1 =  RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {5000, 2}];

pos2 = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {5000, 2}];

list2 = DistanceMatrix[N@pos1, N@pos2];

(l2 = IntegerPart[
 Compile[{{lis, _Real, 2}},
   Position[lis, Except[1.], {2}, Heads -> False],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ][list2]
 ];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {9.70626, Null} *)

(l1 = Position[list2, Except[1.], {2}, 
 Heads -> False];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {5.80316, Null} *)


l1 === l2
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `` CompiledFunctionTools` `` and check whether [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position) compiled (your example probably doesn't compile because of the `Except`):

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

CompilePrint @ Compile[
    {{lis,_Real,2}},
    Position[lis, Except[1.], {2}, Heads->False],
    CompilationTarget->"C"
]

(*
        1 argument
        2 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        Result = T(R2)1

1   T(R2)1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{lis}, Position[lis, Except[1.], {2}, Heads \
-> False]][ T(R2)0]]
2   Return
*)
```

Notice the `MainEvaluate`. When Compile has to call `MainEvaluate` it will be slower than the uncompiled version.

You asked for a faster method. The following is pretty fast:

```
sa = SparseArray[list2, Automatic, 1.];
sa // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.593123, SparseArray[< 12499892 >, {5000, 5000}, 1.]}

Then, you can use the accessor functions like:

```
sa["MatrixColumns"]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.055956, Null}

to get information related to the positions. Depending on what you want to do with the positions, this may be useful.

positions can be obtained using:

```
sa["NonzeroPositions"]//AbsoluteTiming;
(* {0.0689321, Null} *)

sa["NonzeroPositions"] === Position[list2, Except[1.], {2}, Heads -> False];
(* True *)
```

Comment: Worth to mention that simple cases will compile ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint @  Compile[{{lis, _Real, 2}}, Position[lis, 1.],   CompilationTarget -> "C"]`` because one could be surprised it is mentioned in ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[]``

Comment: @Carl so is there a way to make my current implementation faster. I was thinking of using a compiled version of `MapIndexed` but apparently i am having trouble with `Compile[{{list, _Real, 2}}, MapIndexed[If[#1 != 1.0, #2] &, list, {2}]][list2]`